# What is the proper syntax for setcookie() in php 7.3?

Tags: php, setcookie

What is the proper syntax for setcookie() in PHP 7.3?  I usually use setcookie() like this:

```
setcookie("genone", "genoneinfo", "$cookie_expiration_time","/","",1,1);
```

That works, but how do I add the samesite option?  I have tried like this, but it fails with php errors:

```
setcookie("genone", "genoneinfo", "$cookie_expiration_time","/","",1,1,['samesite'=>'Lax']);
```

errors: PHP Warning:  setcookie() expects at most 7 parameters, 8 given zzz.com/index.php on line 73, referer: https://zzz.com/

Thanks,
Todd

Comment: I'm a beginning programmer and do not understand the syntax...  it looks like I need to use a whole bunch of brackets...  Also, they declare all of the variable types in the example...  is that required?  I've never declared variable types in php...

Comment: Brackets in docs denote optional parameters. Types are there so you know what kind of input is accepted for that parameter. Type declarations are meant only for function definitions, not when you call them. You just pass what you need like you did in your code sample in the question, you just have to use the alternative syntax.

Comment: Like this?

setcookie ( "genone" [, "genoneinfo" [, "$cookie_expiration_time" [, "/" [, "" [, 1 [, 1 ]]]]]] ) : bool

Then I have to add the samesite thing...

Like this?:

setcookie ( "genone" [, "genoneinfo" [, "$cookie_expiration_time" [, "/" [, "" [, 1 [, 1 [, "SameSite=Lax" ]]]]]]] ) : bool

Comment: No. As I said, brackets in documentation just mean "optional parameter", as in "you can skip this parameter if it's ok to you to use defaults".

Answer (score 8, accepted):

PHP 7.3 introduced an alternative syntax for [setcookie()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.setcookie):

> An alternative signature supporting an options array has been added. This signature supports also setting of the SameSite cookie attribute.

That means you only supply the first two arguments as you would in the old version and place the remaining ones in an array of options:

```
setcookie('genone', 'genoneinfo', [
    'expires' => $cookie_expiration_time,
    'path' => '/',
    'domain' => '',
    'secure' => true,
    'httponly' => true,
    'samesite' =>'Lax',
]);
```

Here parameter names from the old version become array keys, as per their description in the docs:

> An associative array which may have any of the keys *expires*, *path*, *domain*, *secure*, *httponly* and *samesite*. The values have the same meaning as described for the parameters with the same name.

Comment: You are awesome...  thank you so much!!!  I am reading through the example in the php manual now and comparing to your example so I can fully understand what's happening...  thanks again!  Much appreciated!

Comment: The best answer in 2022! Works very well and its code is more readable! Thank you!